# Send RButton after holding LButton for time

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to make a script that will press the RButton after holding the LButton for a specific amount of time and ignore the left click. I don't know how to go about this.

Pseudo code:

```
timer = 0;

while(LButton down){
add 1 to timer?

if(timer==100){
Send {RButton}
ignore LButton
reset timer
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use A_TickCount as a quick and easy way of measuring the passing of time.

(TESTED)

```
LButton::
StartTime := A_Tickcount
WaitTimeInMilliSeconds = 1000
tooltip trying
while(StartTime+WaitTimeInMilliSeconds > A_Tickcount)
{
     if(!GetKeyState("LButton","P"))
     {
         click ;send the click anyway if it's not held.
         return
     }
}
tooltip this happens after 1000 milli second of continuously holding left mouse button
return
```

If you put this inside a left mouse button hotkey it will reset itself automatically. If you want it looping all the time, you can put the entire thing in an endless loop and reset the starttime instead of `return`

Comment: Not sure how I'm using it wrong but I can't seem to understand how to get it to work.

Comment: I changed the code, it should work fine now, just replace the tooltip with whatever you need. I must have undid one too many changes before I copied it into stack overflow.

Comment: So thanks for the help the script does work but now I can't left click at all. I suppose I would need to check whether it has been less time than WaitTimeInMilliSeconds and send {LButton}?

Comment: Just put a `~` in front of `LButton::` . That makes the click "pass through", so it clicks normally and triggers the hotkey.

Comment: Hmm I would like it to ignore the left click if I hold the LButton, so is there a way I can start the timer with LButton Down and only register a left click after LButton Up and if the timer is less than WaitTimeInMilliSeconds?

Comment: for simplicity I'll edit the code block in my answer to demonstrate how to send the click only after you've released the actual button, assuming it's not held down long enough. Note this would make left click dragging impossible.